# Add reference to assembly which in turn has a project reference

Tags: c#, dll, reference, dependencies, embed

I have solution 1 which has 2 projects -> project A and project B. Project A references project B. (i.e project A is dependent on project B).

I also have solution 2 which has multiple projects. One of the projects here references DLL A (copied into a folder in solution 2 from bin\debug of project A from soln 1).

Solution 2 compiles fine. But during runtime of solution 2 when the code tries to execute some code from DLL A which is dependent on DLL B, it throws an exception which says Could not load file or assembly DLL B. If I add a reference to DLL B, then the error goes away.

Do I HAVE TO refer DLL B or is there some way in which I can avoid referring DLL B in solution 2 because it does not use it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

First order of the business in visual studio is, that if you have access to source codes, csproj, then it is better idea load these projects into each solution where it depends on. Second order of the business is, that best way to reference a library which has project in the solution is to reference the whole project, instead it's dll output. You do not have to solve issues with paths (Debug/Release) and it works somewhat more smooth and during compilation it is certain, that either last updated dll is used or it gets compiled when necessary.

Comment: Thank you ipavlu. I do have control over the sources but I wanted to keep the solution 1 separate bacause it was a more general library.

Answer (score 0):

DLL B needs to be in the output directory of the project in SLN 2 that references DLL A.  You shouldn't need to explicitly reference DLL B in the project, as long as it's physically there.

DLL A will be copied to that same folder automatically when you run, since you gave the project a reference to it.

Assuming that you're running in Debug mode, then by default your output directory should be:

```
(your project directory)\bin\Debug
```

Comment: Yes you are right Ken. Having the DLL B in the output directory is sufficient. There is no need to reference it. 
DLL A is getting copied over to the output directory if Copy to Local is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

if you use any reference DLL in your project which is depends on second DLL, you need to add both DLL in your solution.

so, You'll need to add DLL B also in solution 2 as it is used in DLL A.